# What are all the resources that can be associated with a security group in AWS?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

The AWS docs are almost useless when trying to describe an entire system. Is there any resource or compiled list of all the resources that can belong to a security group and the different types of security groups?

Here is what I have so far:

- EC2-Classic instance
- EC2-VPC instance
- RDS
- ElasticCache

Anything else I'm missing? Any really good doc resource I'm missing?

Comment: ELBs and redshift clusters can also have security groups (in a vpc)

Comment: Security groups can also be associated with themselves or other security groups, as a trusted source of traffic.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The main concept to understand about an AWS Security Group is that **it determines what traffic is permitted in/out of a resource on a virtual network**.

Therefore, think about what can be launched "into" a virtual network:

- Amazon EC2 instances
- Services that launch EC2 instances:

  - AWS Elastic Beanstalk
  - Amazon Elastic MapReduce
- Services that use EC2 instances (without appearing directly in the EC2 service):

  - Amazon RDS (Relational Database Service)
  - Amazon Redshift
  - Amazon ElastiCache
  - Amazon CloudSearch
- Elastic Load Balancing
- Lambda

**Resources do not "belong" to a security group.** Rather, one or more Security Groups are associated to a resource. This is often a difficult concept to understand since Security Groups have similar abilities to firewalls, and firewalls generally "encase" a number of devices. Rather than "belonging to", or "being encased by", a security group, the virtual network simply uses the definitions contained within a security group to determine what traffic to permit in/out of the resource.

For example, imagine two EC2 instances that are associated with a "Web" security group and the security group is configured to permit incoming traffic on port 80. While both instances are associated to the same security group, **they cannot communicate with each other**. This is because they do not "belong" to the security group, and are not "within" the security group. Rather, the security group definition is used to filter traffic in/out of the instances. The security group can, of course, be configured to permit incoming traffic from the security group itself (a self-reference), which really means that incoming traffic is permitted from any resource that is, itself, associated with the security group. (See, I told you that it's a difficult concept grasp!)

Also, a security group is not actually associated with an EC2 instance within a VPC. Rather, the security group is associated with the [**Elastic Network Interface (ENI)**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ElasticNetworkInterfaces.html) that is attached to an EC2 instance. Think of the ENI as a "network card" that links an instance to a VPC subnet. An instance can have multiple ENIs and can therefore connect to multiple subnets. Each ENI can have its own association with security groups. Thus, the actual security groups being used depends upon where the traffic is flow in/out of the instance, rather than actually being associated with the instance.

There are only two "**types**" of security groups:

- EC2 Classic (the legacy network configuration)
- EC2 VPC (the modern private network configuration)

Either type of security group can be associated with any other resource, as long as they are in the same network type (classic or VPC).

Comment: As of today, AWS Lambda should be in the list.

Comment: Boy, AWS really needs an API call that can give all the associated security groups. To go through each of the services and check everything is a pain. Now, I think you get a warning if you are trying to delete a security group that is in use, so the data on all users must be available.

Answer (score 7):

A Lambda Function can also be associated with a Security Group.  That might not have been the case in 2015, when the original answer was written.

Answer (score 3):

Fargate tasks can also be assigned to security groups.

Answer (score 1):

AWS EFS (Elastic File System) needs a security group attached.

> **From the AWS document:**
> To connect your Amazon EFS file system to your Amazon EC2 instance,
> you must create two security groups: one for your Amazon EC2 instance
> and another for your Amazon EFS mount target.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/accessing-fs-create-security-groups.html

Answer (score 0):

interface endpoints can also be associated with security groups, this is a good question and so far not easy to find on AWS documentation.