# Can Instances in the same security groups can communicate each other any how

Tags: amazon-vpc

Can Instances in the same security groups in Amazon VPC can communicate each other any how

Comment: While answering a different question, I think parts of this elaborate answer about security groups can give some valuable context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29745218/6256482

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instances associated with the same security group can’t talk to each other unless you add rules allowing it (with the exception being the default security group). you have to add rules to make them able to communicate.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the rules. The fact that two or more instances are associated with the same security group is not related to the allowed traffic.

Security groups is a set of allowed traffic rules, while the reference point is the instances themselves (meaning incoming traffic into the instance or outgoing traffic from the instance).
The definition whether instances have access to each others depends on the security groups' rules and the network ACLs' rules.

The communication will not be blocked as long there are rules that allow it.
A communication can be RDP, ICMP, HTTP/S and more, but it should be allowed in both security groups and NACLs.

A note to remember: by default, AWS blocks ICMP communication (ping), therefore, although the security group may have "All Traffic" allowed rule a ping request will fail if there is no specific rule that allows it.

Answer (score 6):

**Rules to connect to instances from an instance with the same security group**

To allow instances that are associated with the same security group to communicate with each other, you must explicitly add rules for this.

The following table describes the inbound rule for a security group that enables associated instances to communicate with each other. The rule allows all types of traffic.

| Protocol type | Protocol number | Ports | Source IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 (All) | -1 (All) | -1 (All) | The ID of the security group |

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html

Answer (score -1):

Security Group name used in Source & Destination of FireWall rules

To create Security Group, we need to specify the FireWalled type of  Inbound and Outbound rules.

Each Rule consists of Protocol, port number and Source (for inbound) or Destination (for outbound) IP addresses that are allowed, not denied.

But why is it that we can indicate Source or Destination as the name of a Security Group?

We do that because we want to refer to the IP addresses (for Source or Destination) of another appliance/instance which are associated with that specific Security Group. [Some people say these appliance/instance is in that specific Security Group]. But specifying Security Group or IP address is one thing. For communication to be successful, the allowed protocol and port number should be explicitly stated in the rule as well.